# Konva 3.0.0 Minimal Bundle (tree shaking) Non-TypeScript project

Tags: javascript, konvajs, tree-shaking

In Konvajs 2.5 I used to be able to do minimal importing by targeting specific src files as per the directions in the [Readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/konva).  Example:

```
import Konva from 'konva/src/Core'
import 'konva/src/Layer'
```

With v3.0.0, the entire library is re-written to TypeScript. My app is not in TypeScript and probably won't be for a long time yet. How can I take advantage of treeshaking in 3.0? Am I stuck in the older version? I'd like the performance improvements of 3.0 since I use pattern fill a ton.

Comment: Hello, I am Konva maintainer. At the current moment that is not possible (even with typescript). But I hope to resolve that issue asap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`konva@3.1.2` has support for minimal bundling:

```
import Konva from 'konva/lib/Core';
// now you have Konva object with Stage, Layer, FastLayer, Group, Shape and some additional utils function.
// Also core currently already have support for drag&drop and animations.
// BUT there are no shapes (rect, circle, etc), no filters.

// but you can simply add anything you need:
import { Rect } from 'konva/lib/shapes/Rect';
// importing a shape will automatically inject it into Konva object

var rect1 = new Rect();
// or:
var shape = new Konva.Rect();

// for filters you can use this:
import { Blur } from 'konva/lib/filters/Blur';
```

Comment: This is perfect. I'll install it tonight and test it out.